# BeautifulSoup seems to load for ever or never return anything when trying to scrape data from website

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to print a price change from this website but it never seems to load and returns nothing at all. How can I edit this to fix it? Thanks.

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://earth2.io/"

def spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, features="html.parser")
        for menu in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'row no-gutters'}):
            print(menu.text)
                
     
spider(1)
```

Comment: because it is a js rendered page. 2nd you are not updating your page

Comment: You need some sort of `page += 1` in the loop otherwise the while loop condition is always true.